# Angular ajax POST request not working - gives 404 error

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, spring-mvc

Please help. I am unable to get any hit on server side controller. On Browser everytime I see "404-Not Found" error. I want to pass post data to the server side and want to return any other string from server. Below are my code snippets:-

web.xml servlet mapping:-

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MyController.java:-

```
import....;

@Controller

public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String methodStart(@RequestParam (value="UID",required=true) String json){
      System.out.println("Data recieved is:-"+json);
      return "hello";
    }
  }
```

Client side code:-

```
var params=({
            'UID': 'testdata'
           });
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://192.168.1.103:8081/ProjectName/registration.html',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data:JSON.stringfy(params)
        }).success(function(data){
                console.log("Success Call");
            })

            .error(function(data, status) {
                console.log("Error Block");
            })
```

Comment: Please do not tag AngularJS qestions with `angular`. `angular` is for Angular version 2 and up. Thank you

Comment: Looks to me this problem has nothing to do with Angular at all as it's a server error. Did you try triggering `http://192.168.1.103:8081/ProjectName/registration.html` directly from your browser (using e.g. Postman)?

Comment: Yes, i tried, but it works only in case of GET request and not POST. If I change the type of method as GET in the controller method, it works, but I don't want that, I want method to be POST only as I have to send more data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Change `value = "/registration"` to, for example `value = "/user-registration"` to avoid conflicts with other links
2. Change `http://192.168.1.103:8081/ProjectName/registration.html` to `http://192.168.1.103:8081/ProjectName/registration-user`, cause maybe `.html` suffix confuses Spring.
3. It it will work, change `registration-user` back to `registration` in Spring, and `$http` URL to `http://192.168.1.103:8081/ProjectName/registration` (without `.html` suffix). I don't think you can map AJAX requests in `web.xml` in this way